# Can anyone provide a sketch as to what a wavelet transform of the dirac delta function look like?

Tags: dirac-delta, wavelets

I was trying to motivate the idea of a time frequency localization using wavelet transform to a peer today and I thought the impulse function would be a good example.

In my mind I was thinking of a dot that is at the origin of the time-frequency space, instead of a line as you would get in fourier transform.

However I am uncertain if wavelet transform would indeed provide this result. Can someone show what the wavelet transform of the dirac delta function would look like?